# Multistep Method: Gear's Formula Interpolation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

[image]

Please explain how to do this. How can we use Lagrange Interpolation to derive this formula? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any similar examples. I am not sure how interpolation would allow us to derive this formula. I have never seen Gear's formula before.

Comment: The instructions given above are fairly explicit. Write a formula for the polynomial $q$ given the data points $(t_i,y_i)$. Compute $q'(t_{n+1})$. Remember that there is a constant step size, so $t_{i+1}-t_i = h$.

Comment: So how do I get the polynomial q? I am having trouble starting the problem. From q, I can compute q' and set it equal to f to see if I can get the formula.

Comment: You need a quadratic polynomial that passes through the three points $(t_i, y_i)$ with $i=n-1,n,n+2$.

Comment: I attempted to do this and cannot get the general formula for this interpolation

Comment: Something like $q(t) = y_{n-1} {(t-t_{n})(t-t_{n+1}) \over (t_{n-1}-t_{n})(t_{n-1}-t_{n+1}) } + \cdots $.

Comment: Thank you, I see. Wouldn't q'(tn+1) be 0 then?

Comment: Oh, just for the first term

Comment: I believe I computed the derivative, but how do I get from there to the formula above?

Comment: When you compute $q'(t_{n+1})$ you should have a formula that involves $h, y_{n+1}, y_n, y_{n-1}$. Equate this to $f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ to get the formula above.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
q(t) &=& y_{n-1} {(t-t_{n})(t-t_{n+1}) \over (t_{n-1}-t_{n})(t_{n-1}-t_{n+1}) } + y_{n} {(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n+1}) \over (t_{n}-t_{n-1})(t_{n}-t_{n+1}) } + y_{n+1} {(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n}) \over (t_{n+1}-t_{n-1})(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) }\\
&=&{1 \over 2 h^2} (y_{n-1} (t-t_{n})(t-t_{n+1})  - 2y_{n} (t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n+1})  + y_{n+1} (t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n}) )
\end{eqnarray}

Grinding through the details gives
$q'(t_{n+1}) = {1 \over 2h} (y_{n-1}- 4y_n + 3 y_{n+1})$.

Equating $q'(t_{n+1}) = f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ gives the desired formula.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely understand how to derive it now